# Create a Force Close when a custom exception occurs

Tags: android, exception

For an android library project, I'm trying to create a Force Close that would show a user of this library he has forgotten to do something.

To do so, I tried to create my custom exceptions, and `throw` them, but what I only have is some warning in the LogCat, and nothing more.

Ex:

**MyActivity.java**

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    try {
        this.isMenuButtonOk();
    } catch(MyCustomException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private void isMenuButtonOk() throws MyCustomException{
    if(!this.mOnCreateOptionsMenuHasBeenCalledFlag)
        throw new MyCustomException("OnCreateOptionMenu() needs to call it's parent. Or you need to deactivate the use of the menubutton");
}
```

**LogCat**

```
08-02 18:28:13.507    3866-3866/com.example.testlibrary W/System.err: com.example.testlibrary.MyCustomException: OnCreateOptionMenu() needs to call it's parent. Or you need to deactivate the use of the menubutton
08-02 18:28:13.511    3866-3866/com.example.testlibrary W/System.err: at com.example.testlibrary.lib.MyActivity.isMenuButtonOk(MyActivity.java:286)
08-02 18:28:13.511    3866-3866/com.example.testlibrary W/System.err: at com.example.testlibrary.lib.MyActivity.onResume(MyActivity.java:244)
08-02 18:28:13.511    3866-3866/com.example.testlibrary W/System.err: at com.example.testlibrary.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:304)
08-02 18:28:13.511    3866-3866/com.example.testlibrary W/System.err: at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1184)
08-02 18:28:13.511    3866-3866/com.example.testlibrary W/System.err: at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5082)
08-02 18:28:13.511    3866-3866/com.example.testlibrary W/System.err: at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2565)
08-02 18:28:13.511    3866-3866/com.example.testlibrary W/System.err: at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2603)
08-02 18:28:13.511    3866-3866/com.example.testlibrary W/System.err: at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2089)
08-02 18:28:13.511    3866-3866/com.example.testlibrary W/System.err: at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
08-02 18:28:13.511    3866-3866/com.example.testlibrary W/System.err: at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
08-02 18:28:13.511    3866-3866/com.example.testlibrary W/System.err: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-02 18:28:13.511    3866-3866/com.example.testlibrary W/System.err: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-02 18:28:13.511    3866-3866/com.example.testlibrary W/System.err: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-02 18:28:13.511    3866-3866/com.example.testlibrary W/System.err: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-02 18:28:13.511    3866-3866/com.example.testlibrary W/System.err: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-02 18:28:13.511    3866-3866/com.example.testlibrary W/System.err: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-02 18:28:13.515    3866-3866/com.example.testlibrary W/System.err: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-02 18:28:13.515    3866-3866/com.example.testlibrary W/System.err: at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Do you have any idea on how I could simulate/create this force close when this exception occurs?

Comment: just don't catch the exception and your done. or if you need to catch for some reasaon, rethrow it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `catch` an exception and print the stack trace, yes you get a "warning" and the app does not crash - that is the point of catching Exceptions. Make sure that `MyCustomException` extends `RuntimeException` (or use RuntimeException) and don't declare that `isMenuButtonOk()` method `throws` your exception.

For example:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    this.isMenuButtonOk();
}

private void isMenuButtonOk(){
    if(!this.mOnCreateOptionsMenuHasBeenCalledFlag){
        throw new RuntimeException("OnCreateOptionMenu() needs to call it's parent. Or you need to deactivate the use of the menubutton");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Display a `Dialog` with a single button indicating **Force Close** and for body of that `Button` put this `System.exit(1);`

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).create();

alertDialog.setTitle("An error occured");

alertDialog.setMessage(<your-message>);

alertDialog.setButton("Force Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
             System.exit(1);
         }
    });

alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
     ...
} catch (Exception e) {
  //some code
}
```

This will catch all the exception your application made, because they are all descended from Exception, keep in mind that this is a very depreciated method